# To set the token in the header before redirecting

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using WebFluxSecurity in spring cloud gateway after successful login the redirection happens however the header of redirected url doesn't contain the access_token.

How to set the access_token in the header before redirection? any pointers?

Here are my spring properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-1.client-id=1
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-1.client-secret=secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-1.client-name=uaa
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-1.provider=my-oauth-provider
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-1.scope=user
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-1.redirect-uri-template=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-1.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.my-client-1.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code


spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-oauth-provider.authorization-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-oauth-provider.token-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-oauth-provider.jwk-set-uri=
#spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-oauth-provider.user-name-attribute=name
server.port=8080
```

I have been following this repo: https://github.com/mraible/webflux-oauth2